# I don't understand why I can change the datatype in a dataset I created

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on a project and I've been trying to clean the data.  I found the issue with one dataset. It is stating that the date field has been coded as a TIMESTAMP instead of a DATE.  How can I change this to the correct type I've watched a few videos and do what they suggest, but nothing is working.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pphp0.png) What am I overlooking? Thank you in advance for your help!

Warm regards,
Tyra

I've tried to change the datatype using MONDIFY and CAST functions but neither is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not supported to change the timestamp to date as you will get this error

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE requires that the existing
> column type (TIMESTAMP) is assignable to the new type (DATE)

there are few options to solve this:

here you can replace CAST with SAFE_CAST, this helps if column has blanks in it.

```
option 1: create table again with DATE data type

    create or replace table dataset.yourtablename as ( SELECT CAST( `DATE` as DATE ) as `Date`) )

option 2: alter table to create new column and then load data from old to new column

    ALTER TABLE dataset.yourtablename
    ADD COLUMN NEW_Date_COL DATE;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've never heard of SAFE_CAST! There's so much to learn.  Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Hi @Tyra do you mind you click tick mark on my answer, this will help me increase my reputation within google cloud community

Comment: Hi B@Bihag Kashikar Happy to help! What exactly do I need to check?

Comment: @tyra there's read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379675/who-marks-green-tick-in-stack-overflow :-)